# How to check null and empty condition using Thymeleaf in one single operation?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, isnullorempty

Is there any way to check both null and empty condition in Thymeleaf?

Approach 1

```
1) .variable1?.variable2?.variable3
2) variable!=null 
3) variable!=''
```

If we combine two conditions like (variable!='' And variable!=null) I am having issue when rendering.

I am trying following sample

```
${#strings.concat(#strings.concat('class ',variable1?.variable2), ' ', variable1?.variable2?.variable3)}
```

I also used ***containsKey*** as well but it is behaving differently.

Comment: See `${#strings.isEmpty(variable)}`.  It will check for empty or null and call `trim()`.

Comment: Can you also post what you're trying to do?  It seems like you may really want `th:classappend` but I can't readily tell.

Comment: @vphilipnyc if you've posted your first comment as an answer, you could earn +300 reputation in 18 months. see [proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048650/1429387).

Comment: @naxa Lol, maybe you can buy me a beer with all of those points

Comment: @vphilipnyc ahah! no, problem :) contact me and request your free beer https://t.me/nullgz

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to check null or empty string using thymeleaf expressions, Use this approach : ---

```
<div th:if= "${searchResults.results != null}">
```

OR, this :--

```
<div th:if= "${searchResults.results != ''}">
```

Furthermore, you can check the empty or null object on your controller itself and then send the response on your thymeleaf-html page accordingly, like this :-- 

1.) Your Controller :-

```
 List ls = //some data from you DAO
    if(ls.isEmpty()){
         model.addAttribute("response","NoData");
      }else{
         model.addAttribute("response",ls);
     }
```

2.) Then on your Thymleaf page :- - -

```
<th:block th:if="${response=='NoData'}"> No Data Found </th:block>
```

**PS -** I've answered the same question here which helps the questioner hope it helps you as well :--
[ThymeLeaf: Not Equal expression in th:if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152960/thymeleaf-not-equal-expression-in-thif/51153187#51153187)

Comment: Hi Sumit I have already tried this .I need both null and empty condition as one single operation rather than as separate condition.I hope u understand what I need

Comment: For that use **'or'** in between 2 condition , like this :--  
**<li th:if="${searchResults.results != null} or ${searchResults.results != ''}">** 
Put **""** properly otherwise your page would end up with error.

Comment: Moreover you can also use **'and'** in a similar way like **or** . Just put **and** in between 2 conditions and it'll work.

Comment: hi Sumit I tried with all these approaches but no luck. Let me try one more time and update you .Thanks for your help

Comment: **'or' ** And  **'and'** operator will definitely work with two conditions in thyemleaf cz I've been using the same approach in my project as well.Hope it works out for you as well.

Answer (score 74):

Try `${#strings.isEmpty(variable)}`.

From [Tutorial | Using Thymeleaf | Strings](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings):

```
/*
 * Check whether a String is empty (or null). Performs a trim() operation before check
 */
${#strings.isEmpty(name)}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `${#!string.isEmpty(variable)}` with a **!** in front?

Comment: @FarazDurrani it depends on what you need. `${#strings.isEmpty(name)}` is true if `name` is null or empty. `${!#strings.isEmpty(name)}` or `${not #strings.isEmpty(name)}` is true if `name` is not null and not empty.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: also works with ${#arrays.isEmpty(myArray)}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print only if NOT a null value or empty sting, then:

```
 th:if="${not #strings.isEmpty(variableName)}"
```